# Passing Pageable parameter with GET method in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, get

I am just trying to pass page and size parameters to the following Controller method, but as far as I see, it does not seem to be possible without POST method.

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<Page<PostDto>> getPostList(@RequestBody Pageable pageable) {
    final Page<PostDto> response = postService.getPostList(pageable);
    
    // code omitted
    }
```

Here is my Postman request and body:

```
{
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 3
}
```

So, how can I pass these 2 parameters via GET method properly?

Here is the error message:

> "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller method can be defined as:

```java
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<Page<PostDto>> getPostList(Pageable pageable) {
    final Page<PostDto> response = postService.getPostList(pageable);
    // code omitted
}
```

> The preceding method signature causes Spring MVC to try to derive a
> `Pageable` instance from the request parameters by using the following
> default configuration:
>
> - `page` - Page you want to retrieve. 0-indexed and defaults to 0.
> - `size` - Size of the page you want to retrieve. Defaults to 20.
> - `sort` - Properties that should be sorted by in the format `property,property(,ASC|DESC)(,IgnoreCase)`. The default sort
>   direction is case-sensitive ascending. Use multiple `sort` parameters if you want to switch direction or case sensitivity — for example, `?sort=firstname&sort=lastname,asc&sort=city,ignorecase`.

For reference: [Spring Docs - HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers for Pageable and Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting)

Comment: Very good idea amigo. Actually I used that approach, but thought that it was not a good idea. Now I am surprised as it is mentioned on official documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the method 2 query parameters: pageNumber and pageSize

```
@GetMapping("/getPostList")
public ResponseEntity<Page<PostDto>> getPostList(
               @RequestParam Integer pageNumber,
               @RequestParam Integer pageSize) {
    var pageable = Pageable.ofSize(pageSize).withPage(pageNumber);
    
    final Page<PostDto> response = postService.getPostList(pageable);

    // code omitted
}
```

In the method just create a Pageable object based on this two params.

Your request URL will be look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/getPostList?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20
```

It is pretty common practice to put these parameters in query.

Hope it will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The best practise for passing the parameter in GET request is through query parameters but not the request body. So consider to change it to :

```java
ResponseEntity<Page<PostDto>> getPostList(
   @RequestParam(name = "pageNumber",defaultValue="0") Integer pageNumber,
   @RequestParam(name = "pageSize"  ,defaultValue="20") Integer pageSize) {

  Pageable pageable = Pageable.ofSize(pageSize).withPage(pageNumber);
   // code omitted
 }
```

Then call the endpoint by :

```
GET /posts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10
```

Comment: Thanks. What is "Cannot resolve method 'ofSize' in 'Pageable"? I use Java 11.

Comment: this method is introduced in spring-data-common 2.5.  If you use the version less than it , you can try `Pageable pageable =  PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize)`